# Converting all characters in a string to it's hexadecimal format for values less than 256

Tags: javascript, string, encoding, character-encoding, hex

I need to display all the characters in a string to it's hexadecimal format'\xHH'.The below is the code I have been trying lately.I am able to convert only the first string into it's hexadecimal format.But not all.

```
for(i=0;i<inputString.length;i++){

    if(inputString.charAt(i)<256){

 inputString.replace(inputString .charAt(i),'\\x'+inputString.charCodeAt(i).toString(16));
    }

}
return inputString;
```

Comment: Please show us the strings you are trying to convert so we can see what might be happening and be able to help.

Comment: This was the problem statement"Except for alphanumeric characters, encode all characters with ASCII values less than 256 with the &#xHH;"from OWASP cheat sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem probably it's on the `if` condition, since you are comparing the char to `256`, and not the char code, so you probably want:

```
if(inputString.charCodeAt(i)<256) // instead of inputString.charAt(i)<256
```

For a more functional way, you can use this:

```
string
    .split("")
    .filter(c => c.charCodeAt(0) < 256)
    .map(c => '\\x' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16))
    .join("")
```

```js
let string = "something";
// filtering out the ones greater than 256
console.log(
    string
      .split("")
      .filter(c => c.charCodeAt(0) < 256)
      .map(c => '\\x' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16))
      .join("")
);
// not filtering out the ones greater than 256
console.log(
    string
      .split("")
      .map(c => (c.charCodeAt(0) < 256 ? '\\x' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16) : c))
      .join("")
);
```